# how to convert date into timestamp using timezone

Tags: 8, theming, datetime

I am using strtotime to convert date into time stamp but its does not work correctly. I know its relatively to time zone. My drupal store time zone is denver. I am not sure why its not showing correct date. there is around one day difference. so The last date I used 31 but I get last date of 30th not 31

Here are my query to make date into time and fetch record

```
date_default_timezone_set(drupal_get_user_timezone());
$startdate = strtotime(\Drupal::request()->query->get('startdate')); // 2021-12-01
$endate = strtotime(\Drupal::request()->query->get('enddate')); //2021-12-31
$database = \Drupal::database();
if(!empty($startdate)){
$userrecord = $database->query("SELECT mail, access FROM users_field_data WHERE access BETWEEN $startdate and $endate")->fetchAll();
```

Here is twig where i Called date

```
{{ result.access|format_date('custom', 'F j, Y')|e }}
```

Comment: That DB query is open to SQL injection. Please read https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/database-api/static-queries#placeholders for how to safely handle the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal stores times always in UTC, never in local time. Also Unix timestamps are by definition in UTC.

You can convert a local date string to a timestamp by creating a \DateTime object:

```
$timestamp = (new \DateTime('2021-12-31'))->getTimestamp();
```

Which is using the default PHP timezone or by specifying your own time zone:

```
$timestamp = (new \DateTime('2021-12-31', new \DateTimeZone('America/New_York')))->getTimestamp();
```